# No nbextensions are shown in Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

I did a fresh install of Jupyter Notebook today. It is working as it should be.

After that I tried installing nbextensions but I run into problems when tying to execute:

```
jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
```

I Get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'create_prompt_application' from 'prompt_toolkit.shortcuts' (/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/prompt_toolkit/shortcuts/__init__.py)
```

If I start a notebook I can see the extensions tab but only two modules are shown.

Comment: Check on this [blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/optimizing-jupyter-notebook-tips-tricks-and-nbextensions-26d75d502663) I have given steps for nbextensions installation and usage. See if it works

Comment: Either I don't get it or it doesn't help my problem